# Cannot get border to differ from side-to-side or up-and-down in TableCell javafx 2

Tags: css, tableview, javafx-2, tablecell

I am trying to create a schedule interface within javafx 2+, and I am having trouble getting the TableView to contain TableCells that look like conjoined components.

The first thing that I tried was to use background colors and borders, however, I cannot get the borders to differ between the top and bottom.

`-fx-border-width: 1px, 0px, 0px, 0px;` for top

`-fx-border-width: 0px, 0px, 1px, 0px;` for the bottom

Ideally I would be able to span columns or rows, but I understand that it does not fit the model of the control. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 39):

Just remove commas from your code. E.g.:

```
-fx-border-width: 1 2 3 4; -fx-border-color: red blue green yellow;
```

Comment: and you can also try this
-fx-border-style: hidden hidden solid hidden; if you want to hide some border side

Comment: Why do I get unknown property -fx-border-width with Java FX8 in Eclipse? It also does not work.

Comment: @AndrewS my mind reader is on vacation, please post your code as a separate question :)

Comment: No no, I'm sure the answer is more fundamental than that. It seems not setting a color to the border causes it not to apply. So if one want's a margin a color must be specified. Even setting a transparent color causes odd behavior with TextFields.